# Automatic rollback without any error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rollback

I'm unable to create a row in the DB. Rails apparently starts and then immediately rolls back the transaction without any errors. I'm using sqlite3.

```
  logger.debug("creating billing name...")
  BillingName.create() #also tried BillingName.new.save
  logger.debug("...created")
```

Log file:

```
 creating billing name...
 ^[[1m^[[36m (0.1ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mbegin transaction^[[0m
 ^[[1m^[[35m (0.1ms)^[[0m  rollback transaction
 ...created
```

`select * from billing_name` shows indeed no entry has been added. How can I tell why the transaction is being rejected?

Comment: perhaps BillingName is failing validation?  Try changing your create statement to `BillingName.create!` and see what exceptions Rails throws in your log.

Comment: "How can I tell why the transaction is being rejected?" do this: `BillingName.new(name: 'blabla')` etc, and test it with `.valid?` (also see `.persisted?` to test if the entry is savd in the DB)

Comment: try `billing_name = BillingName.new; billing_name.save; console.log(billing_name.errors.inspect.to_s)` to see what the errors are.

Comment: create! gave me all the error info I needed. errors.inspect works too. Validations were failing. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check the errors after a `save` or `valid?`

```
billing_name = BillingName.new
billing_name.save # or billing_name.valid?
puts billing_name.errors.inspect
```

Comment: Also, `billing_name.errors.full_messages` will give you an array of the errors in a nicer format.

Comment: This saved me!! @spullen

Answer (score 5):

These are good answers that help you find the error by inspecting the model. I use those too.

But I've found that ActiveRecord doesn't always provide useful information, especially in callbacks. `valid?` will be true, errors will be empty, and the console won't show anything except the rollback. So, a good place to look is what is happening in those callbacks, specifically the before_create filter.

Comment: Life saver...  how can i have been such a moron and miss that?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As someone who always uses the bang methods, I recently had a similar issue and could not debug it.
The only thing is, I had upgraded to rails 7.

Yup, so apparently, using `return` inside of a transaction block is no longer supported and will result in a rollback.

[GITHUB: Deprecate committing a transaction exited with return or throw #29333](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29333)